# Using Partitions for a large MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

An update on my attempts to implement a 505,000,000-row table on MySQL on my MacBook Pro:
Following the advice given, I have partitioned my table, tr:

```
i UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL,
j UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL,
A FLOAT(12,8) NOT NULL,
nu BIGINT NOT NULL,
KEY (nu), key (A)
```

with a range on nu. nu ought to be a real number, but because I only have 6-d.p. accuracy and the maximum value of nu is 30000. I multiplied it by 10^8 made it a BIGINT - I gather one can't use FLOAT or DOUBLE values to PARTITION a MySQL table. Anyway, I have 15 partitions (p0: nu<25,000,000,000, p1: nu<50,000,000,000, etc.).
I was thinking that this should speed up a typical to SELECT:

```
SELECT * FROM tr WHERE nu>95000000000 AND nu<100000000000 AND A.>1.
```

to something of the order of the same query on a table consisting of only the data in the relevant partition (<30 secs). But it's taking 30mins+ to return rows for queries within a partition and double that if the query is for rows spanning two (contiguous) partitions.
I realise I could just have 15 different tables, and query them separately, but is there a way to do this 'automatically' with partitions? Has anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: You should use EXPLAIN PARTITIONS to see how the execution plan takes advantage of the partitioning scheme. Queries across different partitions may take more time than an unpartitioned table. You should also check how many rows the query you have pasted here returns.